# HDIV : Hibernate-validator Groups not working

Tags: hibernate, security, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hdiv

Hibernate-validator Groups group validation is not working with  HDIV when i use `<mvc:annotation-driven validator="hdivEditableValidator" />` instaed of `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

My implementing code in ManageBean is

`@NotNull(groups = ApplicantValidation.class) 
    private ApplicantBean applicantDetails;`

and calling code in controller is

`@Validated(ApplicantValidation.class) @Valid ManageBean manage`

Please suggest if i am missing any required configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in [HDIV 2.1.7 version](https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/issues/70).

---

Edit: The issue remains in HDIV 2.1.7 version. It has been fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/commit/260d71714bd5c054b196bfecf2fc0914e24a303b). It will be released in HDIV 2.1.10 version.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some references.

Comment: Using <hdiv.version>2.1.9</hdiv.version>

Answer (score 0):

closed in **2.1.10-SNAPSHOT** now
[Solved](https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/issues/70)